# how to set dynamically property in class?

Tags: c#, oop

This is my base class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey> 
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

And an inherited class from the base class:

```
public class Category : BaseEntity<int>
{
}
```

Access to property:

```
Category.Id;
```

And the question is: how can I change the property name of `Id` dynamically?

Comment: Use [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) , casting ExpandoObject to `IDictionary<string, object>` you can treat the dictionary key as the property name

Comment: You need to set the property name or value?

Comment: set  property name dynamic